# Disable hostname resolution in PAM

Tags: pam, domain-name-system

When authenticating using PAM, PAM exposes the remote host to the module. On the code side of things, it exposes this via PAM_RHOST using pam_get_item(). However, PAM will attempt to resolve the IP address of the remote host to a name, if possible. If that is the case, the remote name gets passed to the module. Is there anyway to force PAM to not resolve the host names, so that the modules always only get the IP address of the authenticating user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not quite what happens: the application using pam is responsible for setting `PAM_RHOST` using `pam_set_item`. So you will need to configure all daemons that use pam for authentication not to do name resolution. e.g. for openssh you would use the `UseDNS no` configuration item.